# How to find $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ of $T:M_{2x2} \to\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I want to find $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ of $T:M_{2x2} \to \mathbb R^3$

$$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}\right)=(a+b-c+d,a+d,a-b-c-d)$$

I thought of getting the span which generates $(a+b-c+d,a+d,a-b-c-d)$

$a(1,1,1)+b(1,0,-1)+c(-1,0,-1)+d(1,1,-1)$

So I'd like to know if the solution can be:
$Im(T)= \operatorname{span}[ (1,1,1),(1,0,-1),(-1,0,-1),(1,1,-1)]$

Am I heading in the right direction or am I totally wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are doing the right thing. You can say more. If, for example, three of the vectors in your span are linearly independent, then they will span all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. (By $\mathbb{R}^3$ I mean what I think you have denoted $\mathbb{R}_3$.)

Are, for example,
$$
(1,1,1)\quad\text{and}\quad (1,0,-1)\quad\text{and}\quad (-1,0,-1)
$$
linearly independent?

Comment: It's linearly independent since
$$\det\begin{bmatrix}1 &1 & -1 \\1  &0 & 0 \\1&-1 &-1 \end{bmatrix}=2$$
 So I have another doubt, in this case can I only find $Im(T)$ by getting the span or is there any other way I can also find it?

Comment: @Yudop: Good job!

Comment: @Yudop: I don't see any easier general approach to do this.